# using rosbag record for recording/joint_states

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi
I am trying to record just the effort of part of the joints, what is the right way to do it?
Thanks
this is what i tried but didn't work:

```
rosbag record -O 3_cm /joint_states/effort/[15]
```

Nachum

**edit**:
I did rosbag record -O 3_cm /joint_states it does make a bag file but it doesn't let me display it in plot mode, only in raw data mode. Can it be changed?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1540/using-rosbag-record-for-recording/joint_states/) by [Nachum](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/50/nachum/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 35 on 2013-02-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/50/nachum/) on 2013-03-03**:
if i do that i get  [ INFO] [1362313142.091380085]: Subscribing to /joint_states/effort/[15]
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'ros::InvalidNameException'
what():  Character [[] at element [21] is not valid in Graph Resource Name [/joint_states/effort/[15]].  Valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9, / and _.
Aborted (core dumped)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Does the following do what you want?

```
rosbag record /atlas/joint_states
```

Given that all the data goes into one message, I don't think you can record just the effort. The rest of the fields (with the exception of the names) will probably be empty, so essentially you will be recording just the efforts if that is what is being published.

---

Originally posted by [david_rusbarsky](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/147/david_rusbarsky/) with karma: 111 on 2013-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nachum](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/50/nachum/) on 2013-03-03**:
I'm able to record it but not in a format that can be plotted with rxbag. i get it as raw numbers